# Reasons why a cookie could be resetting?

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to check if a user has taken a quiz before and if he/she has, I want them to be not able to take the quiz again. I implemented the code to do this by using cookies and for some reason my code refuses to stop a user from taking the quiz again. I've been staring at this for a very long time now so help would be nice!

Notes: $_SESSION["index"] is set to 0 initially from a previous page and $_COOKIE['quizTakers"] is an empty array initially. Each Question comes one at a time.

```
   <?php 
        session_start();
        #get array of quizTakers from cookie
        $addUser = unserialize($_COOKIE['quizTakers']);
        $userN = $_SESSION['username']; 

        #check if user has taken quiz already and make sure you only check once and not after every question submit
        if(count($addUser) != 0 && intval($_SESSION["index"]) == 0 ){
            foreach ($addUser as $user) {
                if( strcmp($userN,$user) ){
                    echo "You already took the quiz! <br \>";
                    echo "<form action=\"changeUser.php\" method=\"post\"> Go Back: <input type=\"submit\"><br \> </form>";
                    exit();
                }
            }
            array_push($addUser, $userN);
            setcookie('quizTakers', serialize($addUser), time()+86400); 
            echo "loop was entered <br />";
        } 
        #if array is empty(this is should execute the every first time someone takes the quiz
        elseif (count($addUser) == 0) { 
            #add user to array if this is first person taking a quiz yo
            array_push($addUser, $userN);
            setcookie('quizTakers', serialize($addUser), time()+86400); 
            echo "cookie added  line 29 <br/>";
        }

        $indexTemp = intVal($_SESSION["index"]);

        if(isset($_SESSION["notFirstIndex"])){
            #get array of correct answers
            $correctAns = $_SESSION["correctAnswers"];
            #get particular answer at current index
            $currentCorrectAns = intval($correctAns[$indexTemp]) +1;


            $userAns = intval($_POST['ans']);
            echo "The User picked: ".$userAns." and the correct Answer was: ".$currentCorrectAns."<br/>";

            if($userAns == intVal($currentCorrectAns)){
                echo " you were correct! <br />";
                $_SESSION["totalCorrect"] += 1;
            }

            else{
                echo "you were wrong";
                $_SESSION["totalIncorrect"] +=1;
            }

        }
        elseif(!isset($_SESSION['notFirstIndex'])){
            echo "Welcome to your quiz, $userN <br />";
            echo "You havent answered any questions yet! <br />";

        }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
    <HR>
    </html>

    <?php


        #When questions are over show results
        if($_SESSION["numQuestions"] == $indexTemp){
            $_SESSION["index"] = 0;
            echo "Your Results are: <br /> ";
            echo "Total Questions: ".$_SESSION["numQuestions"]."<br/>";
            echo "Total Correct: ".$_SESSION["totalCorrect"]."<br/>";
            echo "Total Incorrect: ".$_SESSION["totalIncorrect"]."<br/>";
            $percentage = (intval($_SESSION["totalCorrect"]) / intval($_SESSION["numQuestions"])) * 100 ;
            echo "Percentage Rightht: $percentage % <br/ >";
            echo "<form action=\"process.php\" method=\"post\"> Back to Main screen: <input type=\"submit\"><br \> </form>";

            $takers = unserialize($_COOKIE['quizTakers']);
            echo $takers[0];
            if(count($takers) == 1){
                echo "<br />";
                echo "You were the first Quiz Taker: <br />";
                echo "Total Takers: 1 <br />";
                echo "Number Right: ".$_SESSION["totalCorrect"]."<br/>";
                echo "Number Incorrect: ".$_SESSION["totalIncorrect"]."<br/>";
                echo "Average: $percentage % <br/ >";
                exit();
            }

            exit();
        }

        $filename = $_SESSION["quizOfTheDay"];

        $quizStuff = file($filename);
        $ctr =1;


        $questionInfo = $quizStuff[$indexTemp];

        $questionParse = explode("#", $questionInfo);
        #$_SESSION["correctAns"] = $questionParse[2];
        #echo $_SESSION["correctAns"]." from line 56 <br />";
        $_SESSION['notFirstIndex'] = "true";
        $answerChoices = explode(":",$questionParse[1]);

        echo "$questionParse[0]? <br />";
        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <form action="questions.php" method="post">
            <?php
                foreach ($answerChoices as $answerChoice) {
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='ans' id='q1' value=".$ctr."> <label for='q1'>".$answerChoice."</label> <br />";
                    $ctr +=1;   
                }   
                $_SESSION["index"] = $indexTemp +1;
            ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO!">
        </form>

        </html>
```

Comment: Why are you putting an array of usernames in the cookie? Each user has their own cookies. So either the cookie is set for them or it isn't, it will never contain other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the cookie is set, `$_COOKIE['quizTakers']` doesn't exist, and when you call `unserialize()` on this you set `$addUsers` to `false`. Then when you try to do `array_push($addUser, $userN);`, this fails because `$addUser` isn't an array, so `$addUser` is still `false`. Then you put this into the cookie.

The next time the user runs the script, you read `false` from the cookie, and the username isn't found in this, so you don't stop the user from taking the quiz again.

You're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need to put an array into the cookie, because cookies aren't shared by all the users. Just set a cookie to a simple string and test whether the cookie is set.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['took_quiz'])) {
    echo "You already took the quiz! <br \>";
    echo "<form action=\"changeUser.php\" method=\"post\"> Go Back: <input type=\"submit\"><br \> </form>";
    exit();
}
setcookie('took_quiz', 'true', time()+86400);
```

As others pointed out, users can get around this by clearing cookies. So if you need something more secure, you need to implement a login system and use a database or file to track which users have already taken the quiz.

Comment: Thanks, I will take your advice

Answer (score 0):

I have not read your code, but did you foundamentally understand the concept of a cookie/session?

A cookie will store data at the browser and sends it everytime the website is requested. A session, will store the data on the server, **but** will store a cookie a the clients side to identify the user on subsequent requests.

So the user can simple wipe the cookies (in both cases) and the server does not know, that this user has ever taken the quiz.

What you can try is a combination of IP address and browser metric, but beware that IP adresses can change (very quick ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Cookies could be erased by the user and you wouldn't know if they did your quiz or not .

You may need to force people to register to gain access to your quiz if you want a permanent way to know if they completed them or not as cookies can easily be wiped.